# preg_match and preg_replace in string php

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

`$string = "Lorem Ipsum is #simply# dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard #dummy# text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of #type1# and scrambled it to #make# a #type2# specimen book. It has survived not only #five# centuries, but also the #leap# into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged";`

I have set of hard code words like `"#simply# | #dummy# | #five# | #type1#"`

What I expect as a output is:

1. If hard code words is found in `$string` it should get highlighted in black. like `"<strong>...</strong>"`.
2. If a word in `$string` is within `#...#` but not available in the hard code word list then those words in the string should get highlighted in red.
3. please note that even though we have #type1# in hard code words, if $string contains `#type2#`  or `#type3#` it should also get highlighted .

for doing this I have tried as below

```
$pattern = "/#(\w+)#/";

$replacement = '<strong>$1</strong>';

$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

This gets me all the words which are within #..# tags highlighted.

I'm bad in preg_ can someone help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I really understand your needs, but what about:

```
$pat = '#(simply|dummy|five|type\d)#';
$repl = '<strong>$1</strong>';
$new_str = preg_replace("/$pat/", $repl, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `preg_replace_callback` that takes a callback function as replacement parameter. In the function you can test which capture group has succeeded and return the string according to.

```
$pattern = '~#(?:(simply|dummy|five|type[123])|(\w+))#~';
$replacement = function ($match) {
    if ( empty($match[2]) )
        return '<strong>' . $match[1] . '</strong>';
    else
        return '<strong style="color:red">' . $match[2] . '</strong>';
};

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```